# java iterate list and addFirst at the same time

Tags: java, list, linked-list, iterator, concurrentmodification

When I try to do

```
ListIterator<Integer> iter = list.listIterator(list.size());

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     iter.hasPrevious();
     list.addFirst(iter.previous());
}
```

I get *ConcurrentModificationException*. I know what that means, but how can I **add first** element to a List and **iterate** it at the same time? **Execution time and memory limit are crucial**.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: First of all its not clear. But let me tell you one thing you can't modify a list while iterating over it. Only solution to this is to add using iterator. Now clarify more.

Comment: You are not really iterating properly in this code snippet. Anyway, perhaps you should tell us what your real task is, so we may suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I'm solving a problem, in wich I need to take a tail of a list and put it front in the same order. For example

List: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5    size = 2
List: 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

**QUESTION: How can I iterate and add first element to a LinkedList at the same time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you know the size of the list and therefore the first index to copy - you can either get the `subList` clone and use `addAll(0,..)` or use `get(index++)` and `addFirst(..)`
methods.

Note that iterating on sublist directly while adding might lead to the same issue since subList returns only view of original list. See  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)

However, it's OK to modify the original list as long as the changes are not structural to the subList view (do not affect size or iteration ability).

Comment: Thanks! **subList** and **addAll** methods did the job, but List does not support clone method and there is no need for it.

`list.addAll(0, list.subList(list.size() - size, list.size()));`

Comment: You're welcome. I looked into it again, you're right,  it's OK to modify the original list as long as the changes are not structural to the subList view (do not affect size or iteration ability). I'll update the answer.